How to .copy on a generic case class without directly extending them?
How do I return a copy of a generic case class using the case class .copy method?
I'm trying to achieve the following:
def modifyNumber[T <: { def number: Int }](objectWithNumber: T, numberToReplace: Int): T = {
  objectWithNumber.copy(number = numberToReplace)
}

but I get the error:

value copy is not a member of type parameter T
objectWithNumber.copy(number = numberToReplace)

These case classes come from an automated ORM process so I can't directly extend them. Is there a way around that?
Here's an example of a few case classes:
case class One(someText: String, number: Int)
case class Two(otherStuff: List[Long], number: Int)

I'm able to create generic functions which I can pass either of these two case classes like so:
def addNumber[T <: { def number: Int }](objectWithNumber: T, numberToAdd: Int): Int = {
  objectWithNumber.number + numberToAdd
}

I also tried:
def modifyNumber[T <: Product with Serializable { def number: Int }](objectWithNumber: T, numberToReplace: Int): T = {
  objectWithNumber.copy(number = numberToReplace)
}

but with this I get the same error.
How can I implement modifyNumber such that it can return a copy of the generic? Is this possible on Scala 2.13.10 (the version I'm on).

Does this answer your question? Scala - How do I implement a generic copy method for case classes that extend an abstract class?

copy is a constructor and Scala doesn't allow abstracting over constructors. So you can either use a workaround like macros, lenses, or your own typeclass.

Thanks for the suggestions @GaëlJ. I checked out the question you linked and all the answers but they all involve extending the case classes in question while in my case this is not possible


You have multiple classes that you cannot modify (One, Two, from your ORM)
You want to write polymorphic code that works for all those classes

So, why not just use ad-hoc polymorphism then?

You could use the somewhat standard Lens[A, Int] (e.g. from Monocle), then your modifyNumber would become just a wrapper around the Lenses set-method:
def modifyNumber[T](t: T, newNumber: Int)(using lens: Lens[T, Int]) =
  lens.set(newNumber)(t)


If you don't want to use Monocle, just create something like your own Lens:
trait CanCopyNumber[T]:
  def copy(t: T, n: Int): T

...

def modifyNumber[T](t: T, newNumber: Int)(using c: CanCopyNumber[T]): T =
  c.copy(t, newNumber)




You can make modifyNumber a macro
// libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

//  def modifyNumber[T <: { def number: Int }](objectWithNumber: T, numberToReplace: Int): T = macro modifyNumberImpl
def modifyNumber[T](objectWithNumber: T, numberToReplace: Int): T = macro modifyNumberImpl

def modifyNumberImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(objectWithNumber: c.Tree, numberToReplace: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  q"$objectWithNumber.copy(number = $numberToReplace)"
}

// in a different subproject

case class One(someText: String, number: Int)
case class Two(otherStuff: List[Long], number: Int)
case class Three(otherStuff: List[Long], noNumber: Int)

modifyNumber(One("aaa", 1), 2) // One(aaa,2)
modifyNumber(Two(List(0L), 1), 2) // Two(List(0),2)
// modifyNumber(Three(List(0L), 1), 2) // doesn't compile


Or you can use Shapeless
// libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10"
import shapeless.labelled.FieldType
import shapeless.ops.record.{Selector, Updater}
import shapeless.{HList, LabelledGeneric, Witness}
import shapeless.record._

def modifyNumber[T, L <: HList](
  objectWithNumber: T,
  numberToReplace: Int
)(implicit
  labelledGeneric: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, L],
  selector: Selector.Aux[L, Witness.`'number`.T, Int],
  updater: Updater.Aux[L, FieldType[Witness.`'number`.T, Int], L],
): T = {
  val l: L = labelledGeneric.to(objectWithNumber)
  val l1: L = l.replace[Int](Witness(Symbol("number")), numberToReplace)
  labelledGeneric.from(l1)
}

